# SPFieldMultiLineText.UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary = true

Tags: document-library, spfield

We are running into problems with the 255 character limit on a multiline text field in a document library.  I can change the setting to allow unlimited length, but the following warning is displayed:

> Columns with long text are not supported by most applications for
>   editing documents and could result in a loss of data. Only allow
>   unlimited length if users will be uploading documents through the Web
>   site, and not saving directly from the application.

Data loss is a big concern.  Has experienced problems as a result of allowing the extended length?  Any alternative solutions to allow more than 255 characters?

EDIT: using MOSS 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit that is referred to is for client applications such as Word, Excel, etc.

If you do not plan to use the fields in these applications you can ignore this warning.

Comment: We don't plan on using the fields in the client applications.  However, the documents themselves will be opened in client applications, edited and saved back to the document library.  Can the fields be truncated during this process?